# MODI OCR Text reading issue

Tags: c#, .net, modi

I'm using MODI to read the text in scanned images and do some further parsing based on what I find in the text. However, sometimes it doesn't read the text properly. For example: If I have just the text "GroupScan" in the image, it reads it sometimes as "GroupScan", sometimes as "Gr0upScan" and sometimes as "roupScan". I have no clue as to what can cause this. Here's my code:

```
 MODI.Image image = (MODI.Image)md.Images[0];

 if (image.Layout.Text.ToLower().Contains("groupscan"))
 {
    groupScan = true;
 }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Likely this isn't an issue in your code, but the nature of OCR is that it doesn't always get the right character when scanning an image. 0 and O are very similar characters for example, so its not surprising that it sometimes gets them switched.

Comment: So is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Outside of writing your own implementation? Not really. MODI is the one making the mistake and truth be told any OCR library you use will likely come across some problems.

Comment: Thank you..I feared that would be the case.